# how to call two method with single line in php?

Tags: php, laravel

I have seen in Laravel calling multiple method in the single line, example:

```
DB::get('test')->toJson();
```

I have a cool class and view method in that class.

```
$this->call->view('welcome')->anotherMethod();
```

I would like to call another method also? Where should I make that method?

Comment: in the class (if the previous methud return $this) on in whichever class the previous method returns (return $classIstance)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`DB::get()` seems to be a method returning an object, where you can call other functions (I think a result object of a database query). If you want to call multiple functions on one object in one line, you have to return `$this` in your functions, e.g.:

```
class View {
    public static function factory {
        // The question is: How useful is this factory function. In fact: useless in
        // the current state, but it can be extended in any way
        return new self;
    }

    public function one() {
        // do something
        return $this;
    }

    public function two() {
        // do something
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
$class = new View();
$class->one()->two();
// it's also possible to use the `factory` function
// you should think about, how useful this approach is in your application
$class = View::factory()->one()->two();
```

That's how you can do it in php, if laravel has some helpers for that, i can't say :)

Comment: let me try this if its work i will accept the answer .. but cant it possible without making object .. cant we do this like that viiew::one()->two() ?

Comment: If the static method `one()` of class `view` returns an object of view, yes, why not? Let me update the code to reflect such a factory method. But you should think about, how useful it is :)