# PHP create class object

Tags: php, class, object

How can i make a multifunctional variable from a class?
I have tried this, but i get the error 
Fatal error: Call to a member function doSomethingElse()

I have a class for example

```
class users {

    public_funtion getUser(){}
    public_funtion doSomethingElse(){}
}
```

I want to be able to call 2 functions in one call

```
$users = new Users()
$user = $users->getUser()->doSomethingElse();
```

What is this called? and how do i get this?

Comment: Return your object within the function (`return $this`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple, the first method must return the own instance, to do that you need to return $this in the first method, like that:

```
class Users {
    public function getUser(){ return $this; }
    public function doSomethingElse(){ }
}
```

than you can do that:

```
    $users = new Users()
    $user = $users->getUser()->doSomethingElse();
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer with 100% confidence, but give this a shot (you may need to return something in those functions, perhaps a constructor function as well as seen here?):
[how to call two method with single line in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31585117/how-to-call-two-method-with-single-line-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Seperate Users and user

```
class users {
    public function getUser(){
       bla();
       return $user; 
     }
    }

class user{
  public function doSomethingElse(){}
}

$users = new Users()
$user = $users->getUser()->doSomethingElse();
```

if you make getUser static you can even strike the line where you create instance of class Users

I would not go for doing as much as I can in one line. Strife for readability!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are looking for chaining. You need to return your objects to achieve the goal. Here is an example:

```
<?php
    class Users {
        public function getUser() {
            return $this;
        }

        public function doSomethingElse() {
            return $this;
        }
    }

    $users = new Users();
    $user = $users->getUser()->doSomethingElse();
?>
```